# Which TCP port does Erlang use for connecting to a remote node?

Tags: erlang, tcp, port

I need to open a firewall port so that I can connect from one Erlang node to another. Is there a standard port?

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/yc3wx3a ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can limit the TCP ports used by Erlang to a specified interval using the following kernel app. parameters:

`erl -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 9001 inet_dist_listen_max 9005`

You also need to enable the `4369` TCP port, as it is used by [epmd](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/epmd.html). (This port can also be changed by the `ERL_EPMD_PORT` environment variable.)